# Selenium parsing whole document instead of webelement

Tags: python, selenium

this problem is really driving me crazy! Here's my code:

```
list_divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='myclass']")
print(f'Number of divs found: {len(list_divs)}')  #Correct number displayed
for art in list_divs:
    mybtn = art.find_elements_by_xpath('//button')  #There are 2 buttons in each div
    print(f'Number of buttons found = {len(mybtn)}')  #Incorrect number (129 instead of 2)
    mybtn[2].click()  #Wrong button clicked!
```

The button clicked **IS NOT** in the **art** Html but at the very beginning of webpage!!! Seems like Selenium is parsing the whole document instead of webelement **art**...
I've printed the outerHTML of variable **art** and it's correct: only the div code which contains 2 buttons!!!! So why the `find_elements_by_xpath()` function applied to the webelement **art** is not parsing the div but the whole html page??!!!
Totally incomprehensible for me!

Comment: It would be helpful to have the url of the website you mentioned.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Like I said, I'm trying to click the 2nd button in the div. The thing is: how can the `find_element_by_xpath()` function return an element that is not present in the html code passed to it (variable art) ???? Insane, isn't it ?

Comment: I tried with other elements than button, like span, and it returns all spans in the root html page, not only the ones included in variable art.... This is absolutely a non-sense to me! I've also tested the Xpath with Chrome's developper tools: `//div[@class='myclass']//button` , it returns 124 buttons which is correct: 62 divs with 2 buttons each.

Comment: It acts as if I was doing `mybtn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button")` instead of `mybtn = art.find_elements_by_xpath('//button')`

Comment: I've made many tests, but still incomprehensible. If I do: `buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='myclass']//button"` : the correct number of buttons is returned (124). And then if I do: `buttons[2].click()`: the right button is clicked!

Comment: Hey Jack, have you solved this or still need help? - when you're doing //div[@class='myclass']//button that finds all matching buttons in all matching classes. That's why you get more than 2. If you want a specific div to get just 2 buttons you'll need to make it unique (I. E. Add More attributes or different xpath)... Share a link to your site and we can help :-)

Comment: Still in trouble. It's not a website of mine, it's a website where I have an account so I can't give a link (need to have an account to access the page). The problem is not with the latest code `//div[@class='myclass']//button`. Read all messages above. This is only a test that works fine (to see if the Xpath was good). The real problem is that, as I alreayd wrote, inside the loop, the parser seems to parse the whole webpage instead of the webelement (variable **art**) that contains only the div...

Comment: No buddy can help you unless you provide minimum insights of the problem. How you can do it. provide the url of website if it is public, it may be possible that few of the community members have the account on the website and they might help. another option is that add the html code where all this is happening. remember not to add the screenshot of the code but the actual html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `mybtn = art.find_elements_by_xpath('//button')` where `//button` ignores your search context since it starts from `//`. Change it to:

```py
mybtn = art.find_elements_by_xpath('.//button')
```

Comment: So simple... Works fine! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I can't post any html code (the page is about 1,000 lines long).
So far, the only way I saw to go through this is to avoid parsing webelements and make parsing of entire webpage for each element I need:

```
list_divs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='myclass']")
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='myclass']//button")
```

and then iterate through the lists to access the button I need for each div. Works perfectly like this. I still don't catch how a xpath applied to a given html code can return something that is not inside this html code...
I'll make other tests with other webpages to see if the problem comes from Selenium.
Thanks for help!